# Do vectors in R have the same functionality as a set data type?

Tags: r, vector, set

Someone with familiarity with other programming languages asked me if R had a [set data type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28abstract_data_type%29). Elements of R vectors are numbered and have an order so it seems to me that this distinguishes them from the set data type. However, any of the operations you might do on a set can be performed in R. For example, `append()`, subsetting (including for removing elements), `sample()` for something like enumerate, `length()` to determine size, `%in%` for "is an element of" and you can easily compare membership using things like `intersect()` and `setdiff()` and so forth.

**Questions:**

1. Does R have a specific set data type?
2. Can vectors perform the same kind of functions as a set data type?

Comment: No, and yes, although the question is a bit broad as it stands. (Can it perform *all* functions that a set can? Well, what language and data type are you comparing it to? Hard to say unless you specify which one you're looking for that you can't find)

Comment: Well, R does seem to have "core" set operations implemented natively: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sets.html

Comment: @David Robinson I don't know enough about the set data type and other programming languages to know all of the kinds of possible functions and uses so I'm not sure how to make my question more specific. Perhaps another way to phrase it would be to ask if R would benefit from having a set data type based on the standard uses of the language (data analysis/visualization, organizing and arranging data, regex, linear algebra, modeling etc).

Comment: @syntonicC That seems like an opinion-based question based on possible features a language could have. StackOverflow is generally focused on specific programming problems. What problem does this solve?

Comment: @David Robinson This question would not solve a problem, it is asking about a comparison between different languages. Would this be better suited for the Programming SE? I can ask the question there instead. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it would... are you considering building such a functionality, and wondering whether it would be useful? Are you considering requesting it? (As @Vlo noted, there already are efficient set operators on vectors- it's possible they could be implemented more efficiently, but it also might end up redundant in practice)

Comment: @David Robinson. I am not considering any of those things. It was a question I asked out of curiosity having only average knowledge of R and basic knowledge of programming in general. Given this, I was not really able to know if my question really made sense until you clarified its broadness to me. If anything, I am trying to understand the purpose of the set data type and to confirm if some or all of this functionality is available in R as I suspected. I don't really have an answer to the question yet though but I'm not sure I will end up getting one so I might just delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see this as appropriate for another site since it is clearly about the R language and supported data types. No there is no set "data type", i.e class that will behave like the mathematical set construct although there are functions that perform set-like operations: `unique`, `%in%`, `setdiff`, `intersect`, `union`. (Arguably Q could be thought of as OT b/c it is essentially a request for a package recommendation.) There is a package that implements a set class and it unsurprisingly named: sets.

```
 install.packages("sets")
 library(sets)
 help(pack=sets)
```